# RTMP Stream from Android Device to Wowza

Tags: android, video, stream, rtmp, wowza

I want to stream RTMP from my Android application to my Wowza server. How would this be possible?

Thanks

Comment: if you found solution, please provide it. It will be very helpful. thanks

Comment: is your android application in java?

Comment: @singh did you find any suitable solutions?

Comment: Yes this is possible please have a look this http://www.androidhive.info/2014/06/android-streaming-live-camera-video-to-web-page/

Comment: For all developers, still finding this question, here is the most up-to-date solution, you can check it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38120116/how-to-stream-live-video-from-android-to-wowza-via-rtmp