# How to stream live video from android to Wowza via RTMP

Tags: android, rtsp, rtmp, live-streaming, wowza

Problem that occupied me for last 7 days is implementation of live video streaming from android to WowzaMediaEngine.

I have started my research on official Wowza pages and i was thrilled with existance of GoCoderSDK library for android and IOS. "Small" problem is the price (10k first year, 2k annually) and since i am building application for "small" client, i have tried other libraries:

- [libstreaming](https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming) is ok, in my opinion ugly coded (no hard feelings), with plenty of bugs to fix, but with quite complicated techniques (well done on those). I've tested on Nexus 5 marshmallow and it worked after a while by using MediaCodec and low video resolution. Increasing resolution would switch to MediaRecorder which is mostly not working. On KitKat device, i was not able to start it at all. After 3-4 days of fixes implementation i've give up. Lib seams not to be maintained anymore
- [Media Broadcasting Library](https://wmspanel.com/mobile_library) looks promising but have'nt tried it. Really expensive. 500$/month is simple too much in my opinion.
- [KickFlip](https://github.com/Kickflip/kickflip-android-sdk) is pretty coded, looks nice, great features and they have removed support for RTMP/RTSP. Tried to revert support and failed.
- [RealTimeLibs](http://www.realtimelibs.com/) price is acceptable. Installed Broadcast ME (demo app) from PlayStore, unable to initiate stream. Demo app is constantly crashing. Discouraged, have'nt tried to contact them.

What to do, to buy GoCoderSDK, to rewrite libstreaming library (since i had the best results with it) or to write my own solution (dont know how much time it would take). Huge multimedia experience is required (which i dont have)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not mentioned in question, but i have stumbled upon [JavaCV](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv) library few times, but reviews were not that great. Also i saw few quite positive comments here on SO, so i decided to try it.

At first it is quite confusing (import javacv.jar, import javacpp.jar, import ffmpeg.jar, add a lot .so files to jniLibs with matching versions etc etc). After looking at examples and few raged posts. Answer to this question ([How to f****ing add JavaCV to Android Studio so I can use the f***ing annoying FFmpeg?](https://gist.github.com/vxhviet/cd39621ae768be07dca30e399c36c034)) actually helped me a lot and with help from [Samuel Audet](https://github.com/saudet) (to which i am really grateful), i've succeded to stream video from android via RTMP to Wowza in quality and video options i choose to set.

Since i have lost 7 days of work on this and in return to community i have created [boilerplate (or starterkit) android application for live streaming video to wowza media engine](https://github.com/bajicdusko/JavaCVWowzaStarterKit) so that many other wowza dependant apps in future can be built much faster.

Comment: Its only doing software encoding, right? Do you have any update about [hardware encoding with ffmpeg on android](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HWAccelIntro)? Thanks for sharing btw.

Comment: @kpaxit Thank you, appreciate it. I think it is not using GPU, but not sure. I have checked in JavaCV source code of FFMpegRecoder (https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/blob/master/src/main/java/org/bytedeco/javacv/FFmpegFrameRecorder.java) and as far as I can tell, no usage of -hwaccel. However, it would be a nice feature. Maybe to write to Samuel directly on GitHub, it'd be great if it could be turned on or off by simple method call on recorder instance.

Comment: How did you config your Wowza Sever?

Comment: @hunghd Nothing extraordinary, locally I was using default settings for streaming through RTMP, set stream name and started listening. url was something like: rtmp://username:password@192.168.1.101:1935/live/android where "live" is application name and "android" is stream name.

Comment: Hi I set up the project but my android device just show a black screen does this still work?

Comment: @utdev It should, however, I haven't tried it for along period of time. I hope I'll find a moment tonight to update it a little bit and try it on my own. 
Generally it works, but there are flaws in the implementation, especially running audio recorder in the separate thread with bad synchronization. I'll try to refactor it to RxJava and hopefully it'd be better.

After this solution, I have tried GoCoder from Wowza and it works perfect. It's expensive, I know.

Comment: got one last question, since we are streaming directly rtmp I do not need the wowza streaming engine to show the stream on a webpage correct? Usually one streams rtsp to wowza which decodes that to rtmp to show that in your browser, but now I do not need to do that step correct?

Comment: If you're using this JavaCV implementation, then it does not have to be wowza, but any rtmp service. However, if you're using GoCoderSDK, then it is not possible to stream anywhere but to Wowza Media Engine, as they are using some other protocol.

Comment: Although I'd like to help you @utdev, its impossible for me to even guess what could go wrong in your app. I believe you'll debug and fix it faster then I'd even had the idea ot the problem :)

Comment: OK thanks a lot though